# Поиск плагина для графиков с определенным функционалом

Tags: javascript, svg, canvas, диаграммы, график

Нужен плагин, у которого были бы "подставки" для значений, как на картинке. Желательно для Vue.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

К сожалению, в `Google Charts`, `Chart.js` `Chartist` не нашел такого функционала... но может быть плохо искал?

Comment: kendo ui  но там правда для jquery

Comment: @Санитариум, благодарю за наводку. Там и для Vue есть, но к сожалению, мне не подходит, т.к. эта библиотека платная

Comment: jquery бесплатна